# Java: Adding User Input to ArrayList, ask for another entry until user exits

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I need help creating a loop for user entry in my arrayList. I want the user to enter real numbers continuously until they enter -999 to exit (after that the program will total and average the values). I am new to Java so skills are limited. I want the user to enter an unlimited number of values, then when -999 is entered the program displays the values entered, the total of the values and the average of the values.

```
 static void option2(){   
       Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
       double numEntered;
       ArrayList<Double> list2=new ArrayList<Double>();
       System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");

      while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
             double d = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (d == -999){
            System.out.println("You have ended the arrayList\n");
            break;
        }
        list2.add(d);
       }
```

Comment: So what is current output from the program and what is a desired output? Please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value you get isn't -999 (and if it is, `break` out of the loop). Something like,

```
while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
    double d = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (d == -999) {
        break;
    }
    list2.add(d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it this evening and let you know.